# Building a 3D array from a number of 2D arrays with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's start with 2 2D arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros( (3,4) )
b = np.zeros( (3,4) )
```

Now let's combine them into a 3D array:

```
c = np.stack( (a,b) )
```

Everything fine so far, but how to add an additional 2D array to the 3D array, the following is not working:

```
np.stack( (c,a) )
```

So, my question is how to add an additional layer to the 3D array? (numpy version `1.12.1`)

Comment: `stack` can work with a long list of 2d arrays like that. So if you have to do this repeatedly, append to the list and `stack` once.  `cancatenate` works to add arrays along an existing dimension, but you'll have to add a dimension to the 2d to match those of the existing 3d.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know all of your 2D arrays at the start, you can just stack more than two of them:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((3, 4))
b = np.zeros((3, 4))
c = np.stack((a, b, a))
```

If you already have one "stacked" array and want to add another array to it, you can use e.g. [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate):

If the array you want to add is "flat", you would have to wrap it in a list to make the dimensions match. By default, the arrays are joined along the first dimension (same as if you were to specify `axis=0` in the keyword arguments):

```
>>> c.shape
(2, 3, 4)
>>> np.array([a]).shape
(1, 3, 4)

c = np.concatenate((c, [a]))
```

If both arrays are already "stacked", this will also work:

```
c = np.concatenate((c, c))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a new axis with [`None/np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) at the start of the array to be appended : `a[None,:,:]` or simply `a[None,...]` or just `a[None]` and for stacking use `np.vstack`.

Here's a sample run to make things clear -

```
In [14]: c.shape
Out[14]: (2, 3, 4)

In [15]: d = np.vstack((c,a[None]))

In [16]: d.shape
Out[16]: (3, 3, 4)

In [17]: e = np.vstack((d,a[None]))

In [18]: e.shape
Out[18]: (4, 3, 4)
```

**Workflow**

So, the workflow would be :

1) To start off with `2D` arrays, use new axes for the arrays :

```
c = np.vstack( (a[None],b[None]) )
```

2) For later appending steps, use new axis for the incoming `2D` array and use `np.vstack` to stack with the existing `3D` array -

```
d = np.vstack((c,a[None]))
```

---

**Using `np.concatenate` for performance :**

`np.vstack` under the hoods uses `np.concatenate` as a special case when we need to stack along the first axis. So, if we want to make use of `np.concatenate` maybe for performance reasons to avoid the additional function call overhead, we need to specify the axis of concatenation, which would be the first axis.

Thus, with `np.concatenate` -

```
In [23]: d = np.concatenate((c, a[None]), axis=0)

In [24]: d.shape
Out[24]: (3, 3, 4)

In [25]: e = np.concatenate((d, a[None]), axis=0)

In [26]: e.shape
Out[26]: (4, 3, 4)
```

Comment: @Divakar thanks for the insight, and, yes, `np.concatenate( ( c, a[np.newaxis,:,:] ), axis=0)`  also works

Answer (score 1):

First make *a* the same dimension as *c*
`result= np.append(c, [a], axis=0)`
But it is not effective to change size of numpy arrays unlike of lists